# Declare "NSMapTable StrongObject" in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, foundation

How can I declare an `NSMapTable` in Swift 3? Why doesn't this example from Apple work?

```
let activeLines = NSMapTable.strongToStrongObjectsMapTable()
```

Xcode suggested change to:

```
let activeLines = NSMapTable.strongToStrongObjects()
```

but it still does not work.

I need convert this example to Swift 3

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Listings/TouchCanvas_CanvasView_swift.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMapTable.strongToStrongObjects()` will fail with the error:

```
error: generic parameter 'KeyType' could not be inferred
NSMapTable.strongToStrongObjects()
           ^
```

The class declaration of NSMapTable is:

```
open class NSMapTable<KeyType : AnyObject, ObjectType : AnyObject> : NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding, NSFastEnumeration
```

You need to specify the key and object types of your map table in its declaration:

```
NSMapTable<NSObject, NSObject>.strongToStrongObjects()
```